# Get the date/time on a particular insert

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to get information on when a particular piece of data was put into a MySQL database? Is it possible to do so after the fact? I’m looking around and not seeing anything. I see something about a query cache, but that seems mostly for efficiency reasons, if you’re using the same query frequently.

Note: This is to get data that has been inputted to a database for the past year.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp column to the data.  This is described here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

It is possible to see the update time for a table *post hoc*  Use a query like this on the information_schema table:

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM
   information_schema.tables WHERE
      TABLE_SCHEMA = 'bigdata'
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'hit_log';
```

Where the database name is "bigdata" and the table name is "hit_log"

But unfortunately for your original question, if you do a `desc information_schema.columns`you'll see there isn't a data item like `UPDATE_TIME` for each column.

Also, the update time of each insert is not recorded with the data.

Comment: Ah, that's an after the fact thing, that won't really help me to get data on data that's been inserted for the prior year.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander, yes definitely you will get date of insert after adding new column in table...

Comment: updated answer with further information on meta data on updates held by mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging: SET general_log=1; and then check log file.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think mysql or any other database provide such information for each and every insert implicitly.

To address your concerns you `can add one more column of modified/insert date` to mark entry  of when data inserted or modified (using `timestamp`),

Comment: That is more or less what I had feared.